# How to set patch color in the diagonal Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

[image]Want to draw a river diagonal to the center of the of the world, however ive found that i would have to do a list with all the patches i want to color, is there a faster way to color the diagonal?

Thanks

I need this diagonal, form the middle of the map upwards, Its even tougher to me as its going backwords and doesnt end in the top most middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
ask patches with [pxcor = pycor] [
  set pcolor green
]
```

Draws this:

[image]

And here's a version that does the diagonal in the upper right corner:

```
ask patches with [pxcor + pycor = max-pxcor] [
  set pcolor green
]
```

[image]

Comment: Seth, hello. Thanks! Although what i want is need from another point. Ill attach an image

Comment: Hello seth, I have attached an image showing what i need to do. Thanks again for your imput !

Comment: input* sorry for the mistake

Comment: Hello, I saw a post here of someone using in cone with turtles. So, I created a turtle with size 0 and asked the cone of radius 1. It worked jaja. Surely there s gotta be a better way but that was useful

Comment: I've added code that shows how to do the diagonal in the upper right corner.